# Implicit route binding exceptions firing before OAuth2 authorization

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-5

I'm working on a Laravel 5(.2.x) application that uses the [oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) package (5.1.x).

This package comes with some middleware to determine whether or not the user is authenticated based on an access_token they provide in their request. The [documentation](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/blob/master/docs/getting-started/laravel-5.md) states to register this middleware in the `$routeMiddleware` array (part of the Http Kernel). If I access the application with an invalid access_token, I'm given an HTTP 401 as expected.

I'm making use of implicit route bindings in my Controller, like so:

```
<?php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        return $user;
    }
}
```

This works well - when I pass a valid ID as an authorised user, I get the correct User object in my JSON response. Likewise, when I pass a valid ID as an unauthorised user I get a 401 from the OAuth middleware.

The problem arises when I force an unauthorised request for an *invalid* user, I get the Laravel 404 exception:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException
(No query results for model [App\User])
```

I'd expect to instead be given Access Denied (`League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\AccessDeniedException`) from the package as a normal unauthorised request would. I don't particularly want to give away any information to an unauthorised user other than "you're not authorised".

From what I can gather, this is because Laravel's router deals with any implicit bindings (`Illuminate\Routing\Router::substituteImplicitBindings($route)`) before the custom route middleware is executed.

I'm struggling to get around this - I'm not sure if I'm not understanding how to use middleware correctly, or if this is a limitation of Laravel.

I'm wondering if anyone else has any better solutions, or can tell me that I'm going about this in the wrong way!